# Good compression algorithm for small chunks of data? (around 2k in size)

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a system with one machine generate small chunks of data in the form of objects containing arrays of integers and longs.   These chunks get passed to another server which in turn distributes them elsewhere.

I want to compress these objects so the memory load on the pass-through server is reduced.  I understand that compression algorithms like deflate need to build a dictionary so something like that wouldn't really work on data this small.

**Are there any algorithms that could compress data like this efficiently?**

If not, another thing I could do is batch these chunks into arrays of objects and compress the array once it gets to be a certain size.  **But I am reluctant to do this** because I would have to change interfaces in an existing system.  Compressing them individually would not require any interface changes, the way this is all set up.

Not that I think it matters, but the target system is Java.

Edit:  Would [Elias gamma coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) be the best for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: The arrays of integers and longs -- are any values possible, or are they generally constrained into a smaller range?   Are there repeats / patterns in the arrays?

Comment: @foson  these values could be anything.   I'm sure there is a regular distribution they fall into, but I do not have that information.  They are timestamps and metrics.  I'm sure the longs could be quite large (e.g. unix time)

Comment: Are you sure that deflate won't work on your data? Have you tested it?

Comment: Most general purpose compression algorithms work by finding patterns in the source data and then using an alternate (smaller) coding for those patterns. The only way you're going to beat a general purpose compressor is to identify patterns that the GP compressor can't identify, or by rearranging the data so that the GP compressor *can* identify the patterns.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel - that's why I'm looking for something non-GP.  Elias gamma coding might do the trick.

Comment: A very simple method and one that's surprisingly effective in many cases is to use 7-bit encoding. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint.aspx. This is quite effective when `int` or `long` variables have small values.

Comment: What makes you think standard compression algorithms won't work here? 2k is plenty of data for an algorithm like LZW to work with.

Comment: If an answer is not obvious, then I would suggest you first collect some statistics to help you better understand what is going on, and what actual problem is being experienced in your server.
Without needing an "optimal" solution, it might be that a "Pareto" solution is "good enough".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elias Gamma Coding might actually increase the size of your data.

You already have upper bounds on your numbers (whatever fits into a 4- or probably 8-byte int/long).  This method encodes the length of your numbers, followed by your number (probably not what you want).  If you get many small values, it might make things smaller.  If you also get big values, it will probably increase the size (the 8-byte unsigned max value would become almost twice as big).

Look at the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) of your data packets.  If it's close to the maximum, compression will be useless.  Otherwise, try different GP compressors.  Tho I'm not sure if the time spent compressing and decompressing is worth the size reduction.

Answer (score 3):

If you think that reducing your data packet to its entropy level is at best as it can be, you can try a simple huffman compression.

For an early look at how well this would compress, you can pass a packet through Huff0 :
http://fastcompression.blogspot.com/p/huff0-range0-entropy-coders.html

It is a simple 0-order huffman encoder. So the result will be representative.

For more specific ideas on how to efficiently use the characteristics of your data, it would be advised to describe a bit what data the packets contains and how it is generated (as you have done in the comments, so they are ints (4 bytes?) and longs (8 bytes?)), and then provide one or a few samples.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're currently looking at general-purpose compression algorithms.  The most effective way to compress small chunks of data is to build a special-purpose compressor that knows the structure of your data.

The important thing is that you need to match the coding you use with the distribution of values you expect from your data: to get a good result from Elias gamma coding, you need to make sure the values you code are smallish positive integers...

If different integers within the same block are not completely independent (e.g., if your arrays represent a time series), you may be able to use this to improve your compression (e.g., the differences between successive values in a time series tend to be smallish *signed* integers).  However, because each block needs to be independently compressed, you will not be able to take this kind of advantage of differences *between* successive blocks.

---

If you're worried that your compressor might turn into an "expander", you can add an initial flag to indicate whether the data is compressed or uncompressed.  Then, in the worst case where your data doesn't fit your compression model at all, you can always punt and send the uncompressed version; your worst-case overhead is the size of the flag...

Answer (score 1):

I would have a close look at the options of your compression library, for instance deflateSetDictionary() and the flag Z_FILTERED in http://www.zlib.net/manual.html. If you can distribute - or hardwire in the source code - an agreed dictionary to both sender and receiver ahead of time, and if that dictionary is representative of real data, you should get decent compression savings. Oops - in Java look at java.util.zip.Deflater.setDictionary() and FILTERED.